# Software to host Azure IoT solution on a local network

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have an Azure IOT solution, but a few of my customers had their own servers and they prefer to have all their applications on their machines and not in the cloud. How to make my Azure IOT solution work without access to the Internet?

FYI, the type of solution I'm talking about is a remote management system of various IOT devices on a local network. But I would like it to work both in the Azure cloud and also locally on some server, if possible.

I don't have this solution yet, but I might build one. It would be a web solution to remotely manage IOTs, usually hosted in the Azure cloud but perhaps some customers would like this web to be hosted on their own local servers. The keywords seem to be Azure IoT Hub, Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service, and IoT Edge

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities for you here:

- Use [IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/about-iot-edge#iot-edge-runtime) as a gateway solution. You would install Edge on a machine locally and that server needs to be able to access Azure - at least during deployment. You would then connect your machines to that Edge gateway. You can do all the processing on that Edge gateway if you want to. You do not have to send any data into the Azure if you don't want to.
- If you really don't want any connections to Azure, then IoT Hub on [Azure Stack](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-stack/) will be your other way. However, this is a) a very heavyweight solution and b) so far still in limited preview.